# how to install spacy for python 3.4, windows 7?

Tags: python, installation, spacy

I am trying to install the spacy python library for python 3.4 on windows 7.  i keep getting install errors (the important-looking error messages are below).

I installed it for 2.7, but I can't seem to install it for 3.4.

I tried doing:
pip3.4 install -U spacy

But it does not seem to work.  Does anybody have any ideas? I'm trying to avoid crazy system surgery.  There must be some simple way to do this.

Warning: The nvcc binary could not be located in your $PATH. For GPU capability, either add it to your path, or set $CUDA_HOME

```
warning: no files found matching '*.cpp' under directory 'include'
warning: no files found matching 'buildbot.json'



***********************************************************
WARNING: One of the following dependencies is unresolved:
    ctypes >=1.0.1
    readline >=1.7.1
***********************************************************
```

error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat

---

Cleaning up...
Command C:\Python34\python.exe -c "import setuptools, tokenize;**file**='C:\Users\joe\AppData\Local\Temp\pip_build_joe\spacy\setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(**file**).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), **file**, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\joe\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-sxqy1vof-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\joe\AppData\Local\Temp\pip_build_joe\spacy
Storing debug log for failure in C:\Users\joe\pip\pip.log

Comment: `-U` means upgrade. Have you tried it without that?

Answer (score 0):

In order for python to detect it you must place it in the following directory.
`C:\Python27\`
or where ever python is located.

Comment: BTW for python 2 it probably just auto installed there

Comment: I already have Spacy installed in my python27 folder.  Is it as simple as copy-pasting the spacy folder and the spacy-2.0.9-py2.7.egg-info into the python34 folder? I'm not sure it would be.

Comment: The problem I'm having is that when I install from the command line, it always wants to install to the 2.7 folder.  I want it to install to the python3.4 folder.  I believe the code is somewhat different between the two.

Comment: Just move it to 3.7 folder